# How to resume Boot camp installation?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, catalina

I am using Mac OS 10.15.3 (Catalina).

I was using Bootcamp assistant. I did the following:

- Started the assistant.
- All options were checked (Create a Windows 10 or later install disk, Download the latest Windows support software from Apple, and the last I think was to install windows.)
- The process started normally, it created the installer disk from a windows iso, and downloaded the support software.
- Then it asked me to choose the size for each partition (which I did)
- Then it said Mac may be unresponsive while partitioning...
- Then after some time the Mac restarted (I left it unattended)
- Then I found it had booted back into Mac OS!

The Windows installation hadn't begun!
I can see a bootcamp partition has been made. And that the USB drive has been formatted with the name "WinInstall" and has all the installation files on it.

How do I proceed with the next step of installing Windows 10? If I start boot camp again, it doesn't have an option to install windows - only for "Remove Windows 10 or later version".

If I keep the option key pressed when I restart my Mac, the three drive options I can choose are "Windows", "EFIBoot", and "MyMacDrive".

If I choose "Windows", the screen just remains blank indefinitely. It seems that the "BOOTCAMP" drive is empty.

How do I proceed with the next step of installing Windows ?